# In a md5 hash when will the first collision occur if first five digits are used

Tags: hash, md5

In a md5 hash when will the first collision occur if only first five digits are used for hashing a series of natural numbers.

```
eg:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7....
c4ca4,c81e7,eccbc,...,..
```

eg if 1231 collides with 10423123 then 10423123 with 1231  is the first collision

Comment: There are only 16^5 possible hex strings of length 5.

Comment: I want to create a collision resistant hash.for url shortening purpose,for that I hash the last row number of table with first 5 letter of md5 hash seeing the probability very low 60 * 60 * 60 is it safe to use till 1 billion?

Comment: @Blender [a-z,0-9]:total:36 character => 36^3

Comment: @user2739318: Hex strings consist of only `[a-f0-9]`, which is 16 characters.

Comment: Your first collision occurs between 1172 and 1081.

Comment: You can't "create a collision resistant hash", you have to estimate how many inputs you will need to hash. BTW I'm not sure from where "60*60*60" came from, however the bare minimum "to use till 1 billion" is about 30bits, or at least double that for practical purposes

Answer (score 0):

On average after 16^5 inputs. All numbers from (16^5)+1 and above should give you a collision... this is on average though, and you might get one even before you reach 16^5

Update: Assuming you're hashing an ordered list of natural numbers as per your question, I've just run a quick test and the first collision is (1081, 1172)